# three.js: gap in LineLoop using CircleGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm seeing a gap in my circle I'm drawing with [LineLoop](https://threejs.org/docs/api/objects/LineLoop.html). Here's my code:

```
const discGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(50, 64);
const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
     transparent: true,
     opacity: 0.5,
     color: 0xffffff,
     linewidth: 1.5
});
const zenithEquator = new THREE.LineLoop(discGeometry, lineMaterial);
zenithEquator.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
scene.add(zenithEquator);
```

And here's the result of that:

[image: using LineLoop]

Here's the same thing using [Line](https://threejs.org/docs/api/objects/Line.html) instead of LineLoop:

[image: using Line]

Obviously what I'm seeing is the circle segment here. If I increase or decrease the number of segments, the gap changes accordingly.

But anyways, how do I draw this simple circle without the annoying gap in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`EdgesGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/EdgesGeometry) to generate edges and render with [`LineSegments`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/LineSegments)

```
const discGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(new THREE.CircleGeometry(50, 64));
const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
     transparent: true,
     opacity: 0.5,
     color: 0xffffff,
     linewidth: 1.5
});
const zenithEquator = new THREE.LineSegments(discGeometry, lineMaterial);
zenithEquator.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
scene.add(zenithEquator);
```

Comment: Thanks. Just adding in the `EdgesGeometry` fixes the problem, even when rendering with LineLoop - but I switched to LineSegments on your suggestion because I'm new to 3d stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.shift()` on the array of vertices:

```
const discGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(50, 64);
discGeometry.vertices.shift(); // here you remove the first vertex from the array
const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
     transparent: true,
     opacity: 0.5,
     color: 0xffffff,
     linewidth: 1.5
});
const zenithEquator = new THREE.LineLoop(discGeometry, lineMaterial);
zenithEquator.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(90);
scene.add(zenithEquator);
```